# WPF . NET 3.5 C# Field is already declared / Member with the same name?

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, xaml, namespaces

So, I corrected almost all my mistakes but here is one more important comes in if I can say.So I created a xaml named `MessageBoxEx.xaml`, with a "Loaded name: Window_Loaded", a textblock named "PartTextBlock" and a stackpanel named "PartStackPanel". Here is the xaml code shown above:

```
<Window x:Class="MyProject.MoLib.MessageBoxEx"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    Loaded="Window_Loaded" Height="160" Width="440" WindowStyle="None" AllowsTransparency="true"
    Background="Transparent" WindowStartupLocation="CenterOwner">
<Border CornerRadius="10" BorderBrush="{DynamicResource AccentBrush}" BorderThickness="3"
        Background="{DynamicResource BackgroundBrush}">
    <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical">
        <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" Height="112">
            <TextBlock x:Name="PartTextBlock" Foreground="#000000" TextWrapping="Wrap"
                       Width="400" Height="Auto" Margin="20,34,10,6" TextAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center"/>
        </StackPanel>
        <StackPanel Name="PartStackPanel" Orientation="Horizontal" HorizontalAlignment="Right"/>
    </StackPanel>
</Border>
```

I then put the names of these elements, so that they are referenced and realize a function, in `MessageBoxEx.xaml.cs`, here is the code:

```
  using System;
  using System.ComponentModel;
  using System.Diagnostics;
  using System.Windows;
  using System.Windows.Controls;
  using System.Windows.Input;
  using System.Windows.Markup;
  namespace MyProject.MoLib
{
public partial class MessageBoxEx : Window, IComponentConnector
{
    private string FMessage = string.Empty;
    private string FResult = (string)null;
    private string FBtn0 = (string)null;
    private string FBtn1 = (string)null;
    private string FBtn2 = (string)null;
    internal TextBlock PartTextBlock;
    internal StackPanel PartStackPanel;
    private bool _contentLoaded;

    public string Btn0
    {
        get
        {
            return this.FBtn0;
        }
        set
        {
            this.FBtn0 = value;
        }
    }

    public string Btn1
    {
        get
        {
            return this.FBtn1;
        }
        set
        {
            this.FBtn1 = value;
        }
    }

    public string Btn2
    {
        get
        {
            return this.FBtn2;
        }
        set
        {
            this.FBtn2 = value;
        }
    }

    public string Message
    {
        get
        {
            return this.FMessage;
        }
        set
        {
            this.FMessage = value;
        }
    }

    public string Result
    {
        get
        {
            return this.FResult;
        }
    }

    public TextBlock TextBlock
    {
        get
        {
            return this.PartTextBlock;
        }
    }
    public MessageBoxEx()
    {
        this.InitializeComponent();
    }
    private void Window_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (this.PartTextBlock.Inlines.Count < 1)
            this.PartTextBlock.Text = this.FMessage;
        this.SetupButton();
    }
    protected override void OnMouseLeftButtonDown(MouseButtonEventArgs e)
    {
        base.OnMouseLeftButtonDown(e);
        this.DragMove();
    }
    private void SetupButton()
    {
        if (this.FBtn0 != null)
            this.CreateButton("btn1", this.FBtn0);
        if (this.FBtn1 != null)
            this.CreateButton("btn2", this.FBtn1);
        if (this.FBtn2 != null)
            this.CreateButton("btn3", this.FBtn2);
        Border border = new Border();
        border.Width = 10.0;
        this.PartStackPanel.Children.Add((UIElement)border);
    }
    private void button_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Button button = sender as Button;
        if (button.Name == "btn1")
            this.FResult = "0";
        else if (button.Name == "btn2")
            this.FResult = "1";
        else if (button.Name == "btn3")
            this.FResult = "2";
        this.Close();
    }

    private void CreateButton(string name, string caption)
    {
        Button button = new Button();
        button.Name = name;
        button.Width = 80.0;
        button.Content = (object)caption;
        button.Margin = new Thickness(0.0, 15.0, 4.0, 0.0);
        button.Click += new RoutedEventHandler(this.button_Click);
        this.PartStackPanel.Children.Add((UIElement)button);
    }

    [DebuggerNonUserCode]
    public void InitializeComponent()
    {
        if (this._contentLoaded)
            return;
        this._contentLoaded = true;
        Application.LoadComponent((object)this, new Uri("/MoLib/MessageBoXex.xaml", UriKind.Relative));
    }

    [EditorBrowsable(EditorBrowsableState.Never)]
    [DebuggerNonUserCode]
    void IComponentConnector.Connect(int connectionId, object target)
    {
        switch (connectionId)
        {
            case 1:
                ((FrameworkElement)target).Loaded += new RoutedEventHandler(this.Window_Loaded);
                break;
            case 2:
                this.PartTextBlock = (TextBlock)target;
                break;
            case 3:
                this.PartStackPanel = (StackPanel)target;
                break;
            default:
                this._contentLoaded = true;
                break;
         }
      }
    }
 }
```

Hop, the names turn red and VS says to me: Ambiguous, already same name. Even for InitializeComponent(), IComponentConnector.Connect and _contentLoaded.

Apparently this error disappears when I change the name of the class but if I do that, the class of the .xaml becomes false.

I would also like to point out that if I change the name of the class, the object 'Loaded ="Window_Loaded" ' of the xaml is no longer referenced by the xaml.cs then it becomes red.

So, what could I do to correct that? Is it possible to be able to reference already existing name in `MessageBoxEx.xaml` in `MessageBoxEx.xaml.cs`? I also added the URI method for in case I have wrong to put the same names.

How do you proceed?

Comment: you need to modify `MessageBoxEx.xaml.cs` file, not `MessageBoxEx.g.i.cs`, g.i.cs will be generated automatically by the compiler .

Comment: @Nikita I do not modify `MessageBoxEx.g.i.cs` I modify `MessageBoxEx.xaml.cs`. I have a hard time expressing myself? I will change the way so I specified this

Comment: ...why do you need to implement the [`IComponentConnector`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/System.Windows.Markup.IComponentConnector?view=netframework-4.7) interface in _your_ code?

Comment: @Nikita 
Provides support for named XAML elements and association of event handlers to them...My project is in framework 3.5. 
I will remove it if necessary...
Goal with the problem I have this is going to be hard to undertake any maneuver

Comment: @Nikita ... And `IComponentConnecter` is not the problem of these errors

Comment: Oh, well, add this important clarification to your question (.net 3.5).

Comment: @Nikita Good, that it, I add it

Comment: I do not understand your question. Why are you declaring your own fields named `PartTextBlock` and `PartStackPanel`? One of the consequences of giving an element in your XAML a name is that the XAML compiler automatically generates the necessary field in code-behind with the same name. That done, you should already have access to those fields in your code-behind class, _without declaring it explicitly_. If you still think you have good reason to declare those fields, please improve your question so that the code example is a good [mcve], and you explain why you're duplicating the declaration.

Comment: Huh? When I put a specific name for a button for example, how do I return it several times with the same name in the xaml.cs? Personally, he says "Ambiguous x -x" and "the name is already declared". I started in the WPF not long ago, so you seem to know about it but can you answer that question before closing the subject? Please? Let's say that I want the button named `ButtonSpecial` to open a xaml page, if in the xaml.cs I name it otherwise you say that the compiler will recognize the" button "? Imagine I put several. @Peter Duniho

Comment: @Peter Duhino Dunno what you not understand with my code just above....Even if according to you it is very badly explain I think you will understand with the code. After maybe you will still understand nothing because I'm not English

Comment: Sorry, I don't really follow most of your last two comments. What I do know: when you give a name to an element in XAML, that automatically creates the field with the same name in the C# class. Based on the code above (which is far from a [mcve], never mind a good one), it seems to me you should just remove the `internal TextBlock PartTextBlock;` and `internal StackPanel PartStackPanel;` lines of code.

Comment: I will also point out that, when used correctly, it's almost never necessary to give names to elements in the first place. Your XAML elements should have properties bound to view model properties, and your code-behind should be manipulating view models, not XAML elements directly. But that's a whole separate issue.

Comment: @PeterDuniho 
I just understood, thank you for your help. But can InitializeComponent () not be set multiple times? Because VS tell me "InitializeComponent is ambiguous with..."

Comment: @PeterDuniho 
I found it for InitializeComponent...I changed the name of `void
InitializeComponent` to `void MyProject`.Now it is IComponentConnector.Connect which is highlighted, frankly I am a ball

Comment: @FWin It's because 'Window'-derived classes are always have 'partial' definitions. So even in .net3.5 no need to define and implement your own 'InitializeComponent' method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Get rid of the `IComponentConnector` interface and its members and don't define the fields that you that you define in your XAML markup in your code-behind file. These fields are generated automatically for you so your code-behind class should look like something like this:

```
public partial class MessageBoxEx : Window
{
    private string FMessage = string.Empty;
    private string FResult = (string)null;
    private string FBtn0 = (string)null;
    private string FBtn1 = (string)null;
    private string FBtn2 = (string)null;
    private bool _contentLoaded;

    public string Btn0
    {
        get
        {
            return this.FBtn0;
        }
        set
        {
            this.FBtn0 = value;
        }
    }

    public string Btn1
    {
        get
        {
            return this.FBtn1;
        }
        set
        {
            this.FBtn1 = value;
        }
    }

    public string Btn2
    {
        get
        {
            return this.FBtn2;
        }
        set
        {
            this.FBtn2 = value;
        }
    }

    public string Message
    {
        get
        {
            return this.FMessage;
        }
        set
        {
            this.FMessage = value;
        }
    }

    public string Result
    {
        get
        {
            return this.FResult;
        }
    }

    public TextBlock TextBlock
    {
        get
        {
            return this.PartTextBlock;
        }
    }

    public MessageBoxEx()
    {
        this.InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void Window_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (this.PartTextBlock.Inlines.Count < 1)
            this.PartTextBlock.Text = this.FMessage;
        this.SetupButton();
    }
    protected override void OnMouseLeftButtonDown(MouseButtonEventArgs e)
    {
        base.OnMouseLeftButtonDown(e);
        this.DragMove();
    }
    private void SetupButton()
    {
        if (this.FBtn0 != null)
            this.CreateButton("btn1", this.FBtn0);
        if (this.FBtn1 != null)
            this.CreateButton("btn2", this.FBtn1);
        if (this.FBtn2 != null)
            this.CreateButton("btn3", this.FBtn2);
        Border border = new Border();
        border.Width = 10.0;
        this.PartStackPanel.Children.Add((UIElement)border);
    }
    private void button_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Button button = sender as Button;
        if (button.Name == "btn1")
            this.FResult = "0";
        else if (button.Name == "btn2")
            this.FResult = "1";
        else if (button.Name == "btn3")
            this.FResult = "2";
        this.Close();
    }

    private void CreateButton(string name, string caption)
    {
        Button button = new Button();
        button.Name = name;
        button.Width = 80.0;
        button.Content = (object)caption;
        button.Margin = new Thickness(0.0, 15.0, 4.0, 0.0);
        button.Click += new RoutedEventHandler(this.button_Click);
        this.PartStackPanel.Children.Add((UIElement)button);
    }
}
```

Comment: That it! Thanks very much for this reasoned answer